# Where does Photos.app store the iPhone videos I've imported?

Tags: iphone, photos, video, photos.app

I use my iPhone to take photos and video, then import them onto my Macbook using the new Photos app.

Now I'm trying to find the original videos so I can put them on an external hard drive for a friend to edit. I notice that within the Photos app, if I control-click on my videos, there is no "Reveal in Finder" option. If I do "Get Info" and look at the filename, it says `IMG_6517.MOV`. But when I do a Spotlight search, that file does not come up.

Where does the new Photos app store the originals for photos and videos I've imported?

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the answer by going to `Terminal` and doing `find ./ -name *.MOV -print`.

The `Photos Library` is different from the `iPhoto Library`. If you've upgraded from iPhoto to the new Photos app, then for any video files you've imported, you can find the originals at:

```
~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters
```

This way, you don't need to export your video files; you can just copy them.

1. In Finder, go to Go > Go to Folder
2. Enter `~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters`
3. Navigate to whatever video files you want and copy them to your destination.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply export from the photos library?
Choose "…Originals…" in the menu!